# Mac app UDP data over its own IP

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, udp

Is it possible for an objective-c mac app to send UDP data to its own IP address?

If so, can someone show me an example? code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at http://code.google.com/p/polkit containing Objective-C UDPSocket sample code and MiniUDPSocket to send and receive network data over UDP:

polkit-read-only/Apple-Networking/UDPSocket.h

polkit-read-only/Apple-Networking/UDPSocket.m

polkit-read-only/Networking/MiniUDPSocket.h

polkit-read-only/Networking/MiniUDPSocket.m